# Transfer file from local machine to server using Jmeter

Tags: java, performance, ssh, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and i want to send one file to another server. Is it possible for SSH SFTP to do that? or any other JMeter plugins?

My source file is in my local machine: C:\Users\myuser>\Desktop\Process.xml

and my destination path is: \serverabc\newfolder

Answer (score 0):

If remote server runs Unix or Linux and has SSH server up and running, you will be able to use [SSH Protocol Support](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) in order to transfer the file. You can install the relevant sampler using JMeter Plugins Manager

[image: JMeter SSH Protocol Support]

See [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) article to learn more about options of performing file transfers using JMeter (and load testing this functionality of course)

Comment: Hello, the remote server is actually Windows server.

Comment: Then you should be able to use [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) to copy the file over using `cmd` and `cp` commands

Comment: Hello, now the case is to move file within my local machine. How is that possible?

Comment: The same OS Process sampler, but use `ren` command instead of `copy`